# how to cast a json array into json object

Tags: xquery, marklogic

let $jsonobject :=

```
{
    "a": "val1 as value1",
    "b": "val2 as value2, val3 as value3"
}
```

let $jsonarray :=

```
{
    "a": "val1",
    "b": [
        "a1",
        "a"
    ]
}
```

how are the above two different from each other? How can we convert the json array into json object using xquery?

Comment: In my understanding of JSON both code snippets seem to show an object, the first has two properties named `a` and `b` with string values while the second objects has the property named `a` with a string value and the property named `b` with an array of strings as the value. So I don't quite understand why one variable is named object and the other is named array or how that samples serve as examples of a question to convert a JSON array into an object.

Comment: because when i am using both of these variables in one of my xquery code and trying to do map:get () on both of these it gives me error like := [1.0-ml] XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) map:get(json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), json:array(<json:array xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>)) -- arg2 is not of type xs:string

Comment: both are different frst is json object secondf is json array as per the error

Comment: You can always edit your question and include and format any code snippets there, as well as add the exact error description. Then I guess you have to wait till someone with Marklogic skills gives you an answer.

Comment: json:object is a specialization of map:map. The issue is probably with how you use map:get. I recommend sharing your map:get code along with your object in code that runs in QC, so we can test your issue ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Often, it is easiest to create a mutable map and array data structure and then convert to an immutable JSON object-node() or array-node(), as in:

```
let $jsonobject := xdmp:to-json(
    map:entry("a", "val1 as value1")
    =>map:with("b", "val2 as value2, val3 as value3")
    )
let $jsonarray := xdmp:to-json(
    map:entry("a", "val1")
    =>map:with("b", json:to-array(("a1", "a")))
    )
```

In most cases, immutable JSON nodes are needed only when inserting into the database.  If the mutable map and array structure is sufficient, just omit the call to xdmp:to-json().

Hoping that helps,